# CSS: Select a specific occourence of a certain type of element on an HTML document

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select a a specific occurrence of a type of element in CSS, to style it.

For example:

```
<span>Some random stuff</span>
<p>Occurrence 1 of p</p>
<ul>
<li>Random stuff</li>
<li>More random stuff</li>
</ul>
<p>Occourence 2 of p</p>
<span>Even more random stuff</span>
```

I want to style Occourence 1 and 2 of p in different ways, in external CSS. I know that it would be easier to just use inline CSS, but I need to do it externally. Also, I know I can use an id or class for each occourence of p, but I want to see if I can find a way to do it without that.

Comment: Can you add classes to those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding IDs or classes, it sounds like you're looking for the [**:nth-of-type**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/) CSS pseudo-selector:

```css
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>Some random stuff</span>
<p>Occurrence 1 of p</p>
<ul>
  <li>Random stuff</li>
  <li>More random stuff</li>
</ul>
<p>Occourence 2 of p</p>
<span>Even more random stuff</span>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thats great, and if I edit my code around a bit I can probably make it work. However, is there a pseudo-selector that can find the element even if that element you want selected is inside another element? For example, if the second occurrence of p was in a div, but the first wasn't, and I could still select both using the same selector. Again, that's fine if there isn't, but it would be easier if there was.

Comment: Absolutely! Pseudo-selectors can be combined with regular selectors! To target **only** certain nth `p` tags that are inside a `div`, you can use `div p:nth-of-type(x)`. Stating `div` before hand means that it won't target `p` tags that aren't inside `div` parents. You can even use `div > p:nth-of-type(x)` to target `p` tags that are **direct** descendants :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:nth-of-type()` selector to choose which one you want to style differently.

```
p:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* Code */
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* Code */
}
```

I know you said you didn't want to add an `id`, but you could use a `class` to identify the element.

HTML:

```
<span>Some random stuff</span>
<p class="first">Occurrence 1 of p</p>
<ul>
<li>Random stuff</li>
<li>More random stuff</li>
</ul>
<p class="second">Occourence 2 of p</p>
<span>Even more random stuff</span>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    /* Code */
  }

  .second {
    /* Code */
  }
```

If you only wanted to get the first `<p>` you could `p:first-of-type` such as:

```
  p:first-of-type {
    /* Code */
  }
```

There are many different selector types you can choose from, listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).